I'm dealing with a react-select problem zIndex related
This is the problem: the dropdown of my Select component should open normally, but instead, it pushes the container, activating the overflow-scroll.
I've tried a bunch of solutions I found here, but none of them work entirely. These solutions include adding 'menuPortalTarget={document.body}' to the Select component, assigning a 'zIndex: 9999' to the menu and/or menuPortal components, and using the 'menuPosition: "fixed"' property in the component. I've tried various combinations of these solutions, but either I manage to get the dropdown to open above all components but it doesn't allow me to interact with it (nor does it respond to mouse hover), or I get the dropdown to respond to user actions but it positions itself relative to the modal containing the component instead of the component itself, so it appears in random locations. If you could help me, that would be great because I've been struggling with this for a week. XD
this is how it looks """"normally""""
